# My program.exe has stopped working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    int n, i, a[10], sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Enter the marks of %dth student ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", a[i]);
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    printf("The total sum is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an error in my program?
Everytime I run the program, after entering the marks for the first student, I get an error saying that my program has stopped working!
This happens for most of my programs where I have used arrays!

Comment: Compiler warnings are not just for fun, but should be payed attention. Enable them. Any modern compiler will warn.

Comment: I wonder how many duplicates there are for this — which boils down to "why does my program misbehave if I don't pass pointers to the variables to be processed by the `scanf()` family of functions?"  Finding a canonical duplicate is a problem.

Comment: Well, it would help if C did not have insane handling of arrays.  Someone should have waterboarded Ritchie until he accepted that, to pass an array by address, it required an '&'.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

Pass-by-pointer, not by value. Unfortunately, some compilers cannot perform compile-time type safety checks on calls to `scanf()`. So basically `scanf()` is treating your (uninitialized value in) `a[i]` as a pointer, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, that helped!

Comment: Some compilers (for example, [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JEyQNcmehX06pP88)) supports compile-time type check for `scanf()` and `printf()`. Do enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Some compilers do manage to diagnose misuse of arguments to both the `scanf()` and `printf()` families of functions.

Answer (score 2):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having the wrong type to `scanf()`. You have to pass `int*` to `scanf()`, not `int`, for `%d`.

I also corrected the `#include`s and added input error check.
Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int n,i,a[10],sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Enter the marks of %dth student ",i+1);
        if(scanf("%d",&a[i])!=1){
            fputs("read error\n",stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    printf("The total sum is %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest `fputs`-ing to `stderr`.

Comment: @CoolGuy What do you mean?

Comment: `fputs("read error\n",stdout);` → `fputs("read error", stderr);`

Comment: @CoolGuy What do you think is the merit of not printing newline?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I thought that `fputs` will behave the same way as `puts`, automatically adding a newline character at the end, but now that I've consulted the manual, I realized that I was wrong. So, just `fputs("read error\n",stdout);` → `fputs("read error\n", stderr);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> //stdio not Stdio

int main(void){
    int n,i,a[10],sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Enter the marks of %dth student ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); // &a[i] not a[i]
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    printf("The total sum is %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

`scanf` needs a pointer, not the value.

Comment: You shouldn't include `conio.h` because it isn't used and some environments don't have it.

Comment: @MikeCAT he used. I just removed errors. So thanks you are right